# Seeking open source bulk US DEM or imagery?

Tags: data, dem, united-states

I am looking to create terrain hillshading for my maps that contain a small region of the US. I intend to show about eight to ten states at a time (at about ~1:5,000,000 scale).

It has been some time since I created a map, but if I recall correctly, I believe the options are to either use imagery or a DEM.

Either way I still face a problem:

1. The raster data I have found (Natural Earth) is not of sufficient quality.
2. I cannot find a bulk download option anywhere for open source DEM data or imagery such as the SRTM.

An example of the what I am trying to accomplish is below

[image: map1]
<sub>(source: [bucultureshock.com](http://bucultureshock.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/northeast-shaded-relief-map.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Have you tried to look around on ArcGIS online ?

Comment: Define sufficient quality - what resolution are you looking for? Define 'bulk' - are you wanting a one-click/file solution for the entire country? Because it's doubtful you'll get that. The higher the resolution, the more data, the more pieces you'll have to get. I'd start here: http://eros.usgs.gov/elevation-products

Comment: Does this related question answer your question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27954/definitive-source-for-downloading-dem-data

Answer (score 1):

My favorite source of DEM data is at [viewfinderpanoramas.org](http://www.viewfinderpanoramas.org/dem3.html) It has STRM data that has been massaged in various ways. I think that should be good enough resolution for what you require.

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer http://datagateway.nrcs.usda.gov/ however the max resolution you can download at one time is statewide and I would assume those will be quite large but it is organized well.

Answer (score 0):

My preference is [nationalmap.gov](http://www.nationalmap.gov), they even have a new bulk download tool that simplifies the process of downloading all the tiles quite a bit.